# Adding separate persistenceUnit still looks at broadleaf own entities and fails

Tags: hibernate, persistence-unit, broadleaf-commerce

I followed [this tutorial](http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/persistence-configuration) and set off to add another persistence unit pointing to a separate database. It should not share broadleaf own entities. So...

The core project now holds applicationContext.xml with these new beans:

```
<!-- New data source to our DB -->

<bean id="blMergedDataSources" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="jdbc/in1" value-ref="in1DS" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryIn1PU"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="blJpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="blPersistenceUnitManager" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="in1PU" />
</bean>

<bean id="blPersistenceUnitManager" class="org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.MergePersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:/META-INF/in1_persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.JPAPropertiesPersistenceUnitPostProcessor">
                <property name="persistenceUnitProperties">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="in1PU.hibernate.dialect" value="${in1PU.hibernate.dialect}" />
                        <entry key="in1PU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${in1PU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}"/>
                        <entry key="in1PU.hibernate.show_sql" value="${in1PU.hibernate.show_sql}"/>
                        <entry key="in1PU.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="${in1PU.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}"/>
                        <entry key="in1PU.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="${in1PU.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}"/>
                        <entry key="in1PU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="${in1PU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files}"/>
                        <entry key="in1PU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor" value="${in1PU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor}"/>
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The core project also has file /META-INF/in1_persistance.xml with the following:

```
<persistence-unit name="in1PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/in1</non-jta-data-source>    
    <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
</persistence-unit>
```

Properties for this persistance unit are very similar to blPU ones, for example:

```
in1PU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
in1PU.hibernate.dialect=com.in1.hibernate.SubSQLServer2008Dialect
```

In the admin new resource is added to \admin\src\main\webapp\META-INF\context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/in1" [....] />
```

Also in admin, new jndi resource is set in \admin\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jetty-env.xml:

```
<New id="in1DS" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/in1</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <Set name="driverClassName">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</Set>
            <Set name="url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DB2</Set>
            <Set name="username">xyz</Set>
            <Set name="password">xyz</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

And to applicationContext-datasource.xml, the following was added `<jee:jndi-lookup id="in1DS" jndi-name="jdbc/in1"/>`

The application starts up and fails with the following error message:

```
[artifact:mvn] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: in1PU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
[...]
[artifact:mvn] Caused by: 
[artifact:mvn] org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.ProductImpl.defaultCategory references an unknown entity: org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.CategoryImpl
[artifact:mvn]  at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:109)
```

I am wondering why this new persistence unit looks up ProductImpl class? It is not listed for it to use (in in1_persistence.xml no classes as listed, and `<exclude-unlisted-classes/>` is on). It surely can't see CategoryImpl entity.... What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered my own question after debugging org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration a bit.

In persistence.xml, it is not enough to have just `<exclude-unlisted-classes/>`. The property `hibernate.archive.autodetection` must also be set. **Basically it cannot be null**. The valid values in there are `"class"`, `"hbm"` or `"class,hbm"`, which we don't want, therefore the value can be set to anything, and `"false"` is doing fine job.

So the correct minimal persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence-unit name="in1PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/in1</non-jta-data-source>    
    <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm good to know. From your debugging, do you think this is something that we could alleviate within Broadleaf or is this just a weird quirk from Hibernate that we can't really do anything about?

Comment: It's just the way Hibernate scans jars for entities... `<exclude-unlisted-classes/>` is somehow not enough to stop scanning rest of the entities in a same jar where persistence.xml is. By having that extra `hibernate.archive.autodetection` property with invalid value is fixing it. I actually got the idea from Broadleaf own persistence.xml files :) So the only thing you can do is to add a note to tutorial maybe, beside that there is nothing else really.